# SQLite and sub-sonic

Tags: sqlite, subsonic, subsonic3, windows-phone-7

Does Subsonic supports SQLite, if so can subsonic work with Win7 Phone ?

Answer (score 1):

SubSonic Supports sqlite out of the box - windows phone 7 was never tested nor tried as far as I know - would be an interesting experiment!

Comment: While it may work in theory you will probably need to recompile a new verison of SubSonic.core.dll as it has dependencies which aren't supported on the phone (such as System.Transactions). This also highlights that you won't get all the functionality of SubSonic.